# How do you set kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound via AudioServicesSetProperty?

Tags: iphone

How do you set kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound to 0 using AudioServicesSetProperty? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your SystemSoundID object is "systemSoundID"

```
UInt32 flag = 0;
err = AudioServicesSetProperty(kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound,
                               sizeof(UInt32),
                               &systemSoundID,
                               sizeof(UInt32),
                               &flag);
```

Comment: SystemSoundID soundID;
        int err = AudioServicesSetProperty(kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound,
                                       sizeof(UInt32),
                                       &UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName,
                                       sizeof(UInt32),
                                       &flag);
        
        
        
        
        
               AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (err);